# Detecting palm swipe in Android.

Tags: android, swipe

I am developing an android application in which I need to detect palm swipe. Precisely, I want to trigger a new intent after successful palm swipe over the touch screen. I have no clue where to start for implementing the same.

[image: Palm Swipe]

Please provide some pointers or approaches which can be used to implement the same.

Comment: may be you are looking for this http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/

Comment: I think only a phones like s3 support this out of the box. You might have to implement it yourself. Or just use the "proximity" sensor mentioned by @Pramod